# I couldn't find jar containing org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws2.sqs.SqsIO class

Tags: apache-beam, javadoc

I have recently came across this [java doc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.31.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/aws2/sqs/SqsIO.html) for apache beam. But I couldn't find any relevant jar file with above package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process applies to other artifacts.

1. Look for the directory in the repo. The source code locates under https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/io/amazon-web-services2.
2. Search the directory name in Maven Central. Search `amazon-web-services2` in maven central https://search.maven.org/ and you can get the artifact: https://search.maven.org/search?q=amazon-web-services2

Comment: You are missing a point here. I'm looking for aws2 namespace not aws namespace. All the references you have mentioned has aws namespace not aws2 namespace.

Comment: I'm showing how one can search for a dependency artifact of Beam. First, look for the root directory of the artifact in the repo. Then search the Maven Central by the directory name. If you tried the process, you can find aws2 by searching `amazon-web-services` too.